# Why PowerShell does not 'understand' the instructions of a response file?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have created the following response file (I'm following the examples found in this article: [Working with the C# 2.0 Command Line Compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

```
# MyCodeLibraryArgs.rsp
#
# These are the options used
# to compile MyCodeLibrary.dll

# Output target and name.
/t:library 
/out:MyCodeLibrary.dll 

# Location of C# files. 
/recurse:*.cs 

# Give me an XML doc.
/doc:myDoc.xml
```

Then I try to execute it using the C# Compiler (csc.exe) from the PowerShell:

```
csc @MyCodeLibraryArgs.rsp
```

Then it generates the following error:

```
Cannot expand the splatted variable '@MyCodeLibraryArgs'. Splatted variables 
cannot be used as part of a property or array expression. Assign the result of 
the expression to a temporary variable then splat the temporary variable instead.
At line:1 char:23 + csc @MyCodeLibraryArgs <<<< .rsp
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoPropertiesInSplatting
```

So, I decide to use the prompt (command-line), and it works correctly.

What is the cause (s) of this problem with PowerShell (v.3.0)?

Thanks in advance for your responses and comments.

Answer (score 3):

@ is a special syntax in powershell for "splatting" variables. You want to escape the @ like so

```
 csc `@MyCodeLibraryArgs.rsp
```

Splatting allows you to pass cmdlet arguments in a hashtable. This is convenient if you want to dynamically build the arguments you are passing. It can also be more readable if there are a lot of arguments. More info on splatting [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx).